# Can I programmatically change the font and font size in an email I send?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, smtp, gmail

I'm using code like this to send email:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
     {
       Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
       Port = 587, //465?
       EnableSsl = true,
       DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
       UseDefaultCredentials = false,
       Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
     };
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
     {
       Subject = subject,
       Body = body
     })
{
  smtp.Send(message);
}
```

...and it works just dandy. Now, though, I want to be able to control the size and style of the font used (e.g., Western 12).

### UPDATE

Although I would still like to use a nicer looking font (such as Western), my main problem was having what I call the "box" characters in the body text (that square character). I found that the following rectified that dilemma:

```
body = body.Replace("�", "");
```

(although in Notepad and in the VS Editor it doesn't look like a box, but like a marooned question mark or some such) - in fact, it looks like that here, too, in the formatted version of my question. In the question editor (terminology?) it looks like the square/box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
   Subject = subject,
   IsBodyHtml = true,
   Body = "<strong>" + body + "</strong>"
}
```

You'll get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can send MailMessage as HTML in that case you will get all the formatting benefits of HTML with CSS

But if you want to keep the choice of sending copy of text and html then use [MailMessage.AlternateViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx)

> **Taken from MSDN :** Also use the AlternateViews property to specify copies of an e-mail message in different formats. For example, if you
>   send a message in HTML, you might also want to provide a plain text
>   version in case some of the recipients use e-mail readers that cannot
>   display HTML content.